# Отправка формы с сайта

Tags: php, get

В-общем я в PHP новичок, раньше был такой скрипт (писал по книге), но потерял. Помогите сделать вот такую простенькую вещь. Есть сайт:

`site.com/test/test2/index.php?action=send_s&msisdn=тут_текст&from=тут_второй_текст&msg=тут_третий_текст&submit=Send`

Необходимо сделать, чтобы я смог отправлять форму со своего сайта, но при этом отправлять запрос к тому сайту. И тот сайт не должен выводиться вообще.

Comment: > Необходимо сделать, чтобы я смог
> отправлять форму со своего сайта, но
> при этом отправлять запрос к тому
> сайту.. И тот сайт не должен
> выводиться вообще

Вы сами читали что написали?

Comment: я не знаю, как объяснить.. необходимо сделать php-форму и обращаться к тому сайту, но оставаться на моем сайте

Answer (score 1):

---

```
<?
    $data="var=test&var2=privet";
    $fp = fsockopen("test.ru", 80, $errno, $errstr, 10);
    $out = "POST /file.php HTTP/1.1\n";
    $out .= "Host: test.ru\n";
    $out .= "Referer: test.ru/\n";
    $out .= "User-Agent: Opera\n";
    $out .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\n";
    $out .= "Content-Length: ".strlen($data)."\n\n";
    $out .= $data."\n\n";
    fputs($fp, $out);
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

---

Еще

```
<?
$url = "http://test.ru/patch/file.php?var=23&var2=54"; // это адрес, по которому скрипт передаст данные методом POST. Как видно, здесь указаны переменные, которые будут переданы через GET
$parse_url = parse_url($url); // при помощи этой функции разбиваем адрес на массив, который будет содержать хост, путь и список переменных.
$path = $parse_url["path"]; // путь до файла(/patch/file.php)
if($parse_url["query"]) // если есть список параметров
$path .= "?" . $parse_url["query"]; // добавляем к пути до файла список переменных(?var=23&var2=54)
$host= $parse_url["host"]; // тут получаем хост (test.ru)
$data = "var3=test&var4=".urlencode("еще тест"); // а вот тут создаем список переменных с параметрами. Эти данные будут переданы через POST. Все значения переменных обязательно нужно кодировать urlencode ("еще тест")

$fp = fsockopen($host, 80, $errno, $errstr, 10);
if ($fp)
{
  $out = "POST ".$path." HTTP/1.1\n";
  $out .= "Host: ".$host."\n";
  $out .= "Referer: ".$url."/\n";
  $out .= "User-Agent: Opera\n";
  $out .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\n";
  $out .= "Content-Length: ".strlen($data)."\n\n";
  $out .= $data."\n\n";

  fputs($fp, $out); // отправляем данные

  // после отправки данных можно получить ответ сервера и прочитать информацию выданную файлом, в который отправили данные...
  // читаем данные построчно и выводим их. Конечно, эти данные можно использовать по своему усмотрению.
  while($gets=fgets($fp,2048))
  {
    print $gets;
  }
  fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

В этом примере файл file.php получил переменные:

GET var="23" и var2="54"

POST var3="test" и var4="еще тест"

Comment: спасибо большое, но мне нужно чтобы пользователь сам заполнял форму с моего сайта, а она отправлялась на тот.. как реализовать это?

Comment: <form method="POST" action="" name="">
var1:<input type="text" name="var1" /><br>
var2:<input type="text" name="var2" /><br>
<input type="submit" id="call" name="subm" value="Отправить" 
</form>

нужные тебе данные будут в переменных $_POST['var1'] и $_POST['var2']
их и отсылай.

Answer (score 0):

вы определитесь у вас GET или POST запрос?

```
<form method="POST" action="http://site.com/test/test2/index.php" name="">
```

и все поля с той формы вставьте у себя и отправляйте запрос
если GET
    <form method="GET" action="http://site.com/test/test2/index.php" name="">